# How to set Internet Explorer 9 Download Folder for zip-files?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I found the following [link](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/change-the-default-internet-explorer-9-download-folder/) and tried it to set the Downloadfolder to Downloads in my Homefolder.

But when I download something, it goes somewhere to ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\

Edit:

For regular files that works as expected. But when I download a zip File as in 
http://www.powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=3371 from the download link in the red box, the download goes to ...\Temporary Internet Files\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE go to:

1. Tools
2. Internet options
3. Under the General tab / Browsing History click on Settings
4. Click on move folder
5. Choose the folder you want your downloads go to
6. Click on Ok, and another Ok.

** You might have to logoff/login for the changes to apply **